# Connect Camunda 8 with Spring boot java @ZeebeWorker does not respond

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am trying to connect camunda 8 with Spring Boot. For it, I saw the youtube playlist

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A584K0sExac&list=PLxYSIlUk9lvXWdlUQYkGzj-igFmCdgjtO

Everything worked fine until I reach the video "Camunda 8 - Service Task",  I Try to write the Java code ah him

```java
@Component
public class ProductOrder {
    @ZeebeWorker(type="getProdctOrder", autoComplete = true)
    public void getProdctOrder() {
        System.out.println("Get Product Order!");
    }
}
```

But I do not get any Response, with that I mean there is no message as expected on the console,
Any ideas why this behavior or how to fix this problem?

thank you

Comment: Does your process model contains a service task with definiont type "getProdctOrder"?